# 502 Bad Gateway after adding load balancing layer dockercloud/haproxy between NGINX and Plumber API

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, haproxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, plumber

I am new to plumber, dockercloud/haproxy and NGINX and tried to set up load balancing as described on https://www.rplumber.io/articles/hosting.html. After configuring `nginx.conf` and `docker-compose.yml` as shown below, I start the containers with `docker-compose up`.

**Log of `docker-compose up`**

```
Starting api_plumber_1 ... done
Starting api_lb_1      ... done
Starting api_nginx_1   ... done
Attaching to api_plumber_1, api_lb_1, api_nginx_1
nginx_1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx_1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
lb_1       | INFO:haproxy:dockercloud/haproxy 1.6.7 is running outside Docker Cloud
lb_1       | INFO:haproxy:Haproxy is running by docker-compose, loading HAProxy definition through docker api
lb_1       | INFO:haproxy:dockercloud/haproxy PID: 6
plumber_1  | ARGUMENT '/plumber.R' __ignored__
plumber_1  |
plumber_1  |
plumber_1  | R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) -- "Lost Library Book"
plumber_1  | Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
plumber_1  | Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
plumber_1  |
plumber_1  | R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
plumber_1  | You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
plumber_1  | Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.
plumber_1  |
plumber_1  | R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
plumber_1  | Type 'contributors()' for more information and
plumber_1  | 'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.
plumber_1  |
plumber_1  | Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
plumber_1  | 'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
plumber_1  | Type 'q()' to quit R.
plumber_1  |
lb_1       | INFO:haproxy:=> Add task: Initial start - Compose Mode
plumber_1  | > pr <- plumber::plumb(rev(commandArgs())[1]); args <- list(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8000); if (packageVersion('plumber') >= '1.0.0') { pr$setDocs(TRUE) } else { args$swagger <- TRUE }; do.call(pr$run, args)
nginx_1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
plumber_1  | Loading required package: DBI
nginx_1    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: IPv6 listen already enabled
nginx_1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx_1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx_1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
plumber_1  | Running plumber API at http://0.0.0.0:8000
plumber_1  | Running swagger Docs at http://127.0.0.1:8000/__docs__/
lb_1       | INFO:haproxy:=> Executing task: Initial start - Compose Mode
lb_1       | INFO:haproxy:==========BEGIN==========
lb_1       | INFO:haproxy:Linked service: api_plumber
lb_1       | INFO:haproxy:Linked container: api_plumber_1
lb_1       | INFO:haproxy:HAProxy configuration:
lb_1       | global
lb_1       |   log 127.0.0.1 local0
lb_1       |   log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
lb_1       |   log-send-hostname
lb_1       |   maxconn 4096
lb_1       |   pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
lb_1       |   user haproxy
lb_1       |   group haproxy
lb_1       |   daemon
lb_1       |   stats socket /var/run/haproxy.stats level admin
lb_1       |   ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
lb_1       |   ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-
lb_1       | defaults
lb_1       |   balance roundrobin
lb_1       |   log global
lb_1       |   mode http
lb_1       |   option redispatch
lb_1       |   option httplog
lb_1       |   option dontlognull
lb_1       |   option forwardfor
lb_1       |   timeout connect 5000
lb_1       |   timeout client 50000
lb_1       |   timeout server 50000
lb_1       | listen stats
lb_1       |   bind :1936
lb_1       |   mode http
lb_1       |   stats enable
lb_1       |   timeout connect 10s
lb_1       |   timeout client 1m
lb_1       |   timeout server 1m
lb_1       |   stats hide-version
lb_1       |   stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
lb_1       |   stats uri /
lb_1       |   stats auth stats:stats
lb_1       | frontend default_port_80
lb_1       |   bind :80
lb_1       |   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
lb_1       |   maxconn 4096
lb_1       |   default_backend default_service
lb_1       | backend default_service
lb_1       |   server api_plumber_1 api_plumber_1:8000 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3
lb_1       | INFO:haproxy:Launching HAProxy
lb_1       | INFO:haproxy:HAProxy has been launched(PID: 9)
lb_1       | INFO:haproxy:===========END===========
```

NGINX returns a `502 Bad Gateway` error if I try to visit `http://example.com/api/__docs__/` in the browser. This is the error:

```
nginx_1    | 2021/03/31 11:25:06 [error] 23#23: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 123.456.789.123, server: example.com, request: "GET /api/__docs__/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.3:8000/__docs__/", host: "example.com"

nginx_1    | 123.456.789.123 - - [31/Mar/2021:11:25:06 +0000] "GET /api/__docs__/ HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.43.90 Safari/537.36"
```

When I send a request to `lb` directly with example.com:7000 it works fine. I therefore suppose that I have a wrong configuration in my `nginx.conf`.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  plumber:
    image: myapi:latest
    command: /plumber.R
    volumes:
     - $PWD/plumber/plumber.R:/plumber.R
    restart: always

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    volumes:
     - $PWD/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    restart: always
    depends_on:
     - plumber
     - lb

  lb:
    image: 'dockercloud/haproxy:1.2.1''
    links:
     - plumber
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "7000:80"
```

**nginx.conf**

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        sendfile     on;
        tcp_nopush   on;
        server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts

        server {
                listen 80 default_server;
                listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

                # root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                index index.html index.htm;

                server_name example.com;

                location /api/ {
                        proxy_pass http://lb:7000/;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, how is configured "lb" upstream?

Comment: @NEOhitokiri: I configured it directly at proxy_pass with http://lb:7000/. So I suppose there is not dedicated upstream configuration needed.

Comment: remove last slash in ```location /api/``` (change to: ```location /api```) and check if upstream "lb" can be resolved as IP of some machine, if not then change proxy_pass to IP from container "lb" (```proxy_pass http://ip_from_container:7000;```) and test if port is open (can use nmap: ```nmap -p 7000 ip_from_container``` (change "ip_from_container" for correct IP)

Comment: I understood that since Docker "knows" how to resolve the names of the services, IP addresses are not required here. It seems that the problem disappeared by by changing proxy_pass to http://lb/ (according the log lb listens to port 80 inside the Docker image) and removing the ports argument for lb in docker-compose.yml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the log, lb service is listening to port 80 inside it's Docker container. Changing the location in **nginx.conf** to

```
location /api/ {
  proxy_pass http://lb/;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

the error disappears. Also in **docker-compose.yml** the part

```
ports:
  - "7000:80"
```

can be removed.